Next 13.5.2 does not resolve ESM modules correctly in imported packages
I import package A in a Next JS application.
Package A imports an icon from @mui/icons-material like this import Icon from "@mui/icons-material/Icon".
This causes an error, as Icon looks like this { default: ..., __esModule: true }.
What could be the problem here?
I tried:

Adding a webpack alias from @mui/icons-material to @mui/icons-material/esm
Adding experimental package import optimization
I changed that import to import { Icon } from "@mui/icons-material" but it causes my app bundle to include every icon from that package. What's interesting, @mui/icons-material/esm is included, so Next correctly reads that I'm in an ESM context.
I changed that import to import Icon from "@mui/icons-material/esm/Icon" and it worked as well and the bundle looked good. I don't have control over package A, unfortunately.
If I import that same icon directly in my application it gets tree shaken correctly. If I import it as a default export it works as well. There's something very specific about using it in an imported package that's already a JS file, not TS.

